# Link an ELF binary with a c program

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld, elf

Given only access to a standalone ELF program I want to be able to call a function within the program from my own program.
Let's say the below code is `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int mystery(int a,int b);

int main() {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        printf("mystery(a,b) = %d\n",mystery(a,b));
        return 0;
}
```

The function `mystery` exists in some elf file `not_my_program`.
What I'm trying to do is something along the lines of

```
gcc main.c not_my_program
```

However this gives me an undefined reference error to `mystery` . I've looked for methods 
on forums and found that converting this elf file into a shared object file is not possible. I've also looked into compiling `main.c` into a relocatable object file with

```
gcc -c main.c
```

and then using `ld` to link the elf with `main.o` but I could not figure out how to do it. The elf is 32 bit but I've omitted the `-m32` flag. If the flag is different for `ld` please let me know. Any help would be very much appreciated.

edit:
output of `readelf -h not_my_program`

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x10e0
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          15116 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         11
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         30
  Section header string table index: 29
```

Comment: How was `not_my_program` generated?would `gcc not_my_program main.c` work?

Comment: What is the output of `readelf -h <elf-file-name>` with each of the elf files?

Comment: @Eraklon I added it in the problem

Comment: @KamilCuk ```not_my_program``` was originally a c program I believe. However, I do not have access to the source code.

Comment: Try to compile with `gcc main.c not_my_program -m32` or `gcc -c main.c -o main.o -m32` and `gcc main.o not_my_program -o my_program`...maybe even adding `-m32` here too. Just guessing.

Comment: I have compiled with and without the ```-m32``` flag. Without it I get a file format error on ```not_my_program``` and with it I get the undefined reference error as stated before. I've also tried the ```-c``` route, didn't work. @Eraklon

Comment: Try `nm not_my_program `. The `mystery` symbol should listed if it exists.

Comment: @Eraklon ```000014cf T mystery``` it shows up

Comment: Normally I wouldn't suggest providing external links. But perhaps this is one time where it may be useful to provide a link to the binary (assuming it's not top secret).

Comment: Look up the documentation of `objdump` and try several of its listing options. At least you should be able to find out what architecture and so on is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hacky way worked with a very simple case.

```
[ aquila ~ ] $ cat 1.c
int func (int a) { return a * (a-1) ; }
int main(int argc) { return func (argc) ; }
[ aquila ~ ] $ cc 1.c
[ aquila ~ ] $ ./a.out ; echo $?
0
[ aquila ~ ] $ readelf -s a.out | grep func
    43: 0000000000400487    19 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 func
[ aquila ~ ] $ cat 2.c
#include <stdlib.h>
static __attribute__((constructor)) void main() {
  int (*func)() = (int (*)())0x0000000000400487;
  exit(func(3));
}
[ aquila ~ ] $ cc -fPIC -shared 2.c -o a.so
[ aquila ~ ] $ LD_PRELOAD=./a.so ./a.out ; echo $?
6
```

The caller in 2.c is made into a constructor with an exit so that the main program's `main()` is not called, in an attempt to limit the execution of the code other than the caller and `func()` itself. The return value being 6 instead of 0 shows both that the call worked and that the main program's `main()` did not get called.

Comment: You sir, have a scary knowledge and problem solving ability. Thank you very much this will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

> Given only access to a standalone ELF program I want to be able to call a function within the program from my own program

It sounds like you have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

While what you desire is technically possible, the difficulty of doing this is approximately 1000x of what you have tried so far. If you are not prepared to spend a month or two getting this working, you should look for other solutions.

Effectively you would have to write a custom ELF loader to load `not_my_program` into memory and initialize it, but then call `mystery` instead of `main` in it.

Note also that `mystery` may depend on global data, and that data may be initialized in `main`, so there is *no guarantee* that `mystery` will work at all when called before `main`.

P.S. Would it be sufficient to call `mystery` from a debugger? That can be achieved in under 30 seconds.